# Minimum of subsequences required to convert one string to another

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have been trying to practise algorithm and I stumbled upon this question: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-subsequences-required-to-convert-one-string-to-another-using-greedy-algorithm/

Probably similar question on stackoverflow: [Find minimum concat number of two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806617/find-minimum-concat-number-of-two-strings)

I have been pondering over the example given in the question for sometime but I am unable to figure out the given task.

Can someone help me with understanding the question with some more examples? before I can try to write algorithm?

Comment: show you current work. explain your thought process and where you are stuck

Comment: @Thankyou I didn't asked for solution. I asked for understanding of the question. If I would've understood the question, I won't have asked in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I think the main point of your trouble may be the fact that you don't know how to transform the `B` string.
So the task states that you've to build string `A` out of sub sequences of `B`.

1. All possible sub sequences
   The `B` example string has 31 possible sub sequences I'll not write them all down.
   Just to get the gist I'll use the sequence `ABCD` which has only 16 possible sub sequences.

```
D
C
CD
B
BD
BC
BCD
A
AD
AC
ACD
AB
ABD
ABC
ABCD
```

Sub sequences in general are explained here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subarraysubstring-vs-subsequence-and-programs-to-generate-them/

2. Build string `A`
   Now, after you found all possible sub sequences, is your task to build string `A` from these.
   So basically you've to append these to represent string `A`.
   The goal is to find the minimum amount of these sequences which could do that.
   So if the sequence from above would be be my `B` and `A` would be "ACDB", the solution would be:

```
ACD + B => 2 sub sequences needed
```